# Apereo CAS 4.1.0 - Gradle Build Failing With INVALID_TICKET Message

Tags: java, gradle, single-sign-on, cas, gradlew

I am new to the CAS and gradle both.

I downloaded the CAS code from [here](https://github.com/apereo/cas/releases/tag/v4.2.1/). After extracting the downloaded zip, I ran gradlew.bat file to build the CAS project. Even if I have not modified anything, I get below error during the build:

```
org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImplTests > verifyDelegateTicketGrantingTicketWithProperParams FAILED
    org.jasig.cas.ticket.InvalidTicketException at CentralAuthenticationServiceImplTests.java:174

47 tests completed, 1 failed
:cas-server-core:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cas-server-core:test'.
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/newbie/Downloads/cas-4.2.1/cas-server-core/build/reports/tests/index.html
```

As the build was failing, I tried with latest version of CAS, CAS 5.0.2.
Building the latest version is also giving the same error:

```
org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImplTests > verifyDelegateTicketGrantingTicketWithProperParams FAILED
    INVALID_TICKET
        at org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createProxyGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:256)
        at org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d0ec6e1f.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bd39a43.createProxyGrantingTicket()
        at org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImplTests.verifyDelegateTicketGrantingTicketWithProperParams(CentralAuthenticationServiceImplTests.java:175)

47 tests completed, 1 failed
:core:cas-server-core:test FAILED
:lintGradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:cas-server-core:test'.
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/newbie/Downloads/cas-5.0.2/core/cas-server-core/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

Can anybody please help me to solve/understand the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be your gradlew.bat files is having a task to run test files. while running the test files one of the test case is failed, because of that your build is failed. If you really want to run the test cases you have to fix the test case error (find which test case is failed and the reason to fix better to check log files). otherwise you can remove the particular test case or  comment the test run task from your gradle build file.